# Space Removal In Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name']))
    {
        $var = $_GET['name'];
        $newvar =str_replace (" ", "", $var);
        $sql = "SELECT varpin, ABS( varpin - '".$newvar."' ) AS pin FROM tbladstore ORDER BY pin LIMIT 5";

    }
?>
```

Here `name` have value `682 031`.In table `varpin` is stored as `xxx xxx`.Here i want to remove the space of `varpin` value when selecting using query.

That is after this step

```
 `$newvar =str_replace (" ", "", $var);`
```

the `$newvar` have the format xxxxxx.so i also need varpin is in this format for finding nearest values of a given pin number.How can i do this?

In db the varpin is in varchar type.I also need this field as only varachar not changed to other type.

Comment: Is there any real need for `varpin` to be a `VARCHAR`? Otherwise; why not store it in a numeric column?

Comment: yes there have real need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `REPLACE(varpin, ' ', '')` to get rid of all spaces in `varpin` column.

And then use `CONVERT(value, DECIMAL)` to make it into a numeric type.

```
CONVERT(REPLACE(varpin,' ',''), DECIMAL)
```

Documentation:

- [MySQL :: REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)
- [MySQL :: CONVERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).

```
 TRIM($newvar)
```